# hasOwnProperty - prototype - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, prototype, hasownproperty

I am trying to exclude the property c if found so it won't be added to the properties array, however, it is being added still. Why?

```
var letters = function () {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 20;
};

letters.prototype = {
  c: 10
};

var letters = new letters();

function looping(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("c")) {

      properties.push(key);
    }
  }
  return properties;

}

looping(letters);
```

Comment: what result do you expect/want from `looping`? Do you perhaps mean to use `!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` rather than `!obj.hasOwnProperty("c")`?

Comment: or just `if (key === 'c') {`...

Answer (score 2):

I changed `!obj.hasOwnProperty("c")` to `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`. This will display properties that do not belong only to the prototype (which I assumed was your goal from the use of `obj.hasOwnProperty`). If, as some other answers assume, your goal is to exclude only the property `"c"`, you could change if condition to `if ( key !== "c" )`.

```
var letters = function () {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 20;
};

letters.prototype = {
  c: 10
};

var letters = new letters();

function looping(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

      properties.push(key);
    }
  }
   return properties;

}

 looping(letters);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to say is something like this

```js
var Letters = function() {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 20;
};

Letters.prototype = {
  c: 10
};

var letters = new Letters();

function looping(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key !== "c") {

      properties.push(key);
    }
  }
  return properties;

}

alert(looping(letters));
```

You should also change constructor function letters to be `Letters`, with capital "l", and not use the same name for both constructor and instance

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are always checking whether your object has an *own* property `c`. Since `c` is in the prototype chain of your letters instance (with which you are overriding your function reference, by the way!), this check will always result in `false`.

I'm not entirely sure if you only want to exclude `c` on the prototype chain specifically or if you want to exclude all properties from the prototype? I'm going to assume the first option in the following code:

```
var Letters = function () {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 20;
};

Letters.prototype = {
  c: 10
};

var myLetters = new Letters();

function looping(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key !== 'c' || obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      properties.push(key);
    }
  }
  return properties;

}

looping(myLetters);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `for` loop will go through all the `keys` from the actual object and its prototype and you are actually sabotaging `hasOwnProperty` by using `"c"` in the call `obj.hasOwnProperty("c")` and negating it. So there is no effect of `hasOwnProperty` at all.

The right way to do is:

```
function looping(obj){
    var properties=[];
    for (var key in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            properties.push(key);
        }
    }
        return properties;
}
console.log(looping(letters));  //prints ["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

hasOwnProperty method doesn't look up for property in prototype chain. Instead just use *in* (like `'c' in obj`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are checking if the `c` exists as property within your `obj` which will always be `false` since your obj wont have the "**ownProperty**" c by prototype functionality as far as i know. Since you are negating the expression `obj.hasOwnProperty("c")` it will always be true, thus pushing every key in your array. Maybe you want something like this.

```
function looping(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if(key !== "c") properties.push(key);
  }
  return properties;
}
```